# compare two arrays and remove object by object id javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

my tried code is :

```js
    const data1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'dd' }, { id: 2, name: 'dd' }, { id: 3, name: 'dd' }, { id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];
    const sasas = [];
    const data2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'dd' },{ id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];
    data2.map((io) => {
     sasas.push(io.id);
     });
    
    sasas.forEach((ik) => {
     for (let i = 0; i < data1.length - 1; i++) {
       if (data1[i].id === ik) {
          data1.splice(i, 1);
            }
          }
      });
    console.log(data1);
```

i have two arrays and i map the **data2** data and getting id values into **sasas**.

then forEach the **sasas** data ,

and use forloop to **splice** the index data of the **data1**.

then getting the answer is  id :1 , id:3, id:5  **objects** in **data1**.

but my expected out put is :

```
const data1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'dd' },{ id: 3, name: 'dd' }];
```

please help me !

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski  yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following 2 approaches. Also, in place of creating an Array you can use Set (better performance)

**Update existing array using while loop**

```js
const data1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'dd' }, { id: 2, name: 'dd' }, { id: 3, name: 'dd' }, { id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];
const data2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'dd' },{ id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];

const sasas = data2.reduce((a,{id}) => a.add(id), new Set())
let i = 0;
while(i < data1.length) {
  if(sasas.has(data1[i].id)) {
    data1.splice(i,1);
  } else i++;
}
console.log(data1);
```

**Create new array using Array.filter**

```js
const data1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'dd' }, { id: 2, name: 'dd' }, { id: 3, name: 'dd' }, { id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];
const data2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'dd' },{ id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];

const sasas = data2.reduce((a,{id}) => a.add(id), new Set())

const result = data1.filter(({id}) => !sasas.has(id));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `temp = new Set(data2.map(({id}) => id)` would be simpler

Comment: @HMR - That is simpler to see but I think with this approach total iterations will be 2n whereas the approach I have followed will have n iterations.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
data1.filter(x=> !data2.some(y=> y.id==x.id ))
```

```js
const data1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'dd' }, { id: 2, name: 'dd' }, { id: 3, name: 'dd' }, { id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];
const data2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'dd' },{ id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];

let result = data1.filter(x=>!data2.some(y=>y.id==x.id))

console.log(result);
```

Above short solution time complexity is *O(n*m)*, below  *O(n+m)* version (n,m are arrays lengths):

```
let h = {}; data2.map(x=>h[x.id]=1); 
let result = data1.filter(x=>!h[x.id]);
```

```js
const data1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'dd' }, { id: 2, name: 'dd' }, { id: 3, name: 'dd' }, { id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];
const data2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'dd' },{ id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];

let h = {}; data2.map(x=>h[x.id]=1);     // we use hash map with data2 ids
let result = data1.filter(x=>!h[x.id]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you could use that map better, instead of

```
data2.map((io) => {
    sasas.push(io.id);
});
```

you could simply:

```
sasas = data2.map(io => io.id);
```

**Your error:**

```
for (let i = 0; i < data1.length - 1; i++) {
```

That means you never check the last index of the array, you can either change the `<` to a `<=` or simply remove the `-1`.

This should work:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
```

**Array.filter**

The functionality you are trying to achieve is easily obtainable via .filter() function, like this:

```js
    const data1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'dd' }, { id: 2, name: 'dd' }, { id: 3, name: 'dd' }, { id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];
    const data2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'dd' },{ id: 4, name: 'dd' }, { id: 5, name: 'dd' }];
    const sasas = data2.map((io) => io.id);
    
    var result = data1.filter(e => sasas.indexOf(e.id) === -1)
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of this loop, i is stopped at data1.length - 2

```
for (let i = 0; i < data1.length - 1; i++) {
```

Variable i should be from 0 to data1.length - 1, which makes the condition become

```
i < data1.length
```